# KineticJS: How to convert a Stage into a HTML5 Canvas Element?

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, kineticjs

I have a KineticJS stage with a lot of layers.

I found this post: [How to copy a kineticjs stage to another canvas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13615387/how-to-copy-a-kineticjs-stage-to-another-canvas)

It says that I get a canvas element from a layer as

```
var canvasElement = layer.getCanvas().getElement();
```

**Is it also possible to export a stage into a canvas?**

Comment: @lavrton I want to save the image in a phonegap container with this plugin: https://github.com/devgeeks/Canvas2ImagePlugin Therefore I need a Canvas Element. How do I get it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your use case you can do this:

1. In hard way you can create custom canvas element (or `Kinetic.Layer`), then conver Stage to Image, draw the image to canvas (layer) then pass it to plugin.
2. But this way should also work. I just saw plugin source. It is very simple (js part). I edited it:

   ```
   stage.toDataURL({
       callback : function(data) {
           var imageData = data.replace(/data:image\/png;base64,/,'');
           return cordova.exec(function() {
               // done callback
           }, function() {
               // fail callback
           }, "Canvas2ImagePlugin","saveImageDataToLibrary",[imageData])
       }
   });
   ```

Comment: My example is not working? You should not edit plugin source. Just use this code, instead of call plugin.