# KineticJS: How to convert a Stage with n Layers to a Canvas?

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, kineticjs

I have seen this question [How to copy a kineticjs stage to another canvas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13615387/how-to-copy-a-kineticjs-stage-to-another-canvas) it shows that you can convert a layer into a canvas as:

```
var canvasElement = layer.getCanvas().getElement();
```

and the context like this:

```
var context = layer.getCanvas().getContext();
```

But if I have a Stage with n, n > 1 layers how do I convert all the layers to one Canvas?

Answer (score 1):

You say "convert all the layers to on Canvas"...implying an html5 canvas rather than something Kinetic.

Example code and a Demo:  http://jsfiddle.net/m1erickson/CBxUj/

```
var canvas=document.createElement("canvas");
var ctx=canvas.getContext("2d");
document.body.appendChild(canvas);

stage.toImage({
    x:0,
    y:0,
    width:stage.width(),
    height:stage.height(),
    callback:function(img){
        canvas.width=img.width;
        canvas.height=img.height;
        ctx.drawImage(img,0,0);
    }
});
```